# removing duplicates from n grams in rows python

Tags: python, n-gram

This code produces n-grams and the number of counts the n gram appears.
I have a csv file with rows and a column containing string of words for every row.
This code for example when it searches gets a 4 gram like 'this is my puppy' it also counts the number of occurrences it occurs in that same row.
My intention is that when it gets an occurrence of n-gram in a row it should count it once and count its second time in a another row and so on.

```
e.g  row         Word
      1          this is my puppy what this is my puppy
      2          this is my puppy
```

so this code counts 'this is my puppy' as  3 times. Yet i want it to be 2 times

**This is the  python code**

```
import collections
import re
import sys
import time


def tokenize(string):
    """Convert string to lowercase and split into words (ignoring
    punctuation), returning list of words.
    """
    return re.findall(r'\w+', string.lower())


def count_ngrams(lines, min_length=4, max_length=5):
    """Iterate through given lines iterator (file object or list of
    lines) and return n-gram frequencies. The return value is a dict
    mapping the length of the n-gram to a collections.Counter
    object of n-gram tuple and number of times that n-gram occurred.
    Returned dict includes n-grams of length min_length to max_length.
    """
    lengths = range(min_length, max_length + 1)
    ngrams = {length: collections.Counter() for length in lengths}
    queue = collections.deque(maxlen=max_length)

    # Helper function to add n-grams at start of current queue to dict
    def add_queue():
        current = tuple(queue)
        for length in lengths:
            if len(current) >= length: 
                ngrams[length][current[:length]] += 1

    # Loop through all lines and words and add n-grams to dict
    for line in lines:
        for word in tokenize(line):
            queue.append(word)
            if len(queue) >= max_length:
                    add_queue()

    # Make sure we get the n-grams at the tail end of the queue
    while len(queue) > min_length:
        queue.popleft()
        add_queue()

    return ngrams


def print_most_frequent(ngrams, num=10):
    """Print num most common n-grams of each length in n-grams dict."""
    for n in sorted(ngrams):
        print('----- {} most common {}-grams -----'.format(num, n))
        for gram, count in ngrams[n].most_common(num):
            print('{0}: {1}'.format(' '.join(gram), count))
        print('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage: python ngrams.py filename')
        sys.exit(1)

    start_time = time.time()
    with open("PWorm.csv") as f:
        ngrams = count_ngrams(f)
    print_most_frequent(ngrams)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print('Took {:.03f} seconds'.format(elapsed_time))
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of populating you `ngrams` semi-manually, you can use a `defaultdict`

To prevent the same ngram in a line to count twice, you'll have to make an ngram-dict per line, and then combine that with the general ngram dict

```
def count_ngrams(lines, min_length=4, max_length=5):
    """Iterate through given lines iterator (file object or list of
    lines) and return n-gram frequencies. The return value is a dict
    mapping the length of the n-gram to a collections.Counter
    object of n-gram tuple and number of times that n-gram occurred.
    Returned dict includes n-grams of length min_length to max_length.
    """
    lengths = range(min_length, max_length + 1)
    ngrams = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
    queue = collections.deque(maxlen=max_length)

    # Helper function to add n-grams at start of current queue to dict
    def add_queue(ngrams_line):
        current = tuple(queue)
        for length in lengths:
            if len(current) >= length: 
                ngrams_line[length][current[:length]] = 1  # instead of += 1

    # to combine the 2 defaultdict(Counter)            
    def combine_ngrams(ngram, ngramline):
        for k, v in ngramsline.items():
            ngrams[k] += v
        return ngrams

    # Loop through all lines and words and add n-grams to dict
    for line in lines:
        ngrams_line = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
        for word in tokenize(line):
            queue.append(word)
            if len(queue) >= max_length:
                    add_queue(ngrams_line)
        ngrams = combine_ngrams(ngrams, ngrams_line)


    # Make sure we get the n-grams at the tail end of the queue
    ngrams_line = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
    while len(queue) > min_length:
        queue.popleft()
        add_queue(ngrams_line)
    ngrams = combine_ngrams(ngrams, ngrams_line)

    return ngrams
```

I don't 100% understand the part after `while len(queue) > min_length:`, or why the `queue` doesn't get reset everyline, you you'll might have to adjust my answer a bit

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It has worked the way i needed it. Thanks  so much once again